# How do I authenticate the source of my javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ssl, particles.js

I'm using particles.js as background on a website and have recently implemented a SSL certificate which has disabled it and in Chrome I get a notification saying: 'This page is trying to load script from unauthenticated sources' I'm presuming it will be a similar message for Safari and Firefox.

Both parts the particles.min.js and app.js files are being hosted on my servers and I'm using Wordpress as my CMS. When I allow the script to be loaded all is fine.

How would I resolve this?

Thanks

J-P

Comment: Are they loaded with http not https?

Comment: As in the url of the link within the <script> tag, if so they are http url, which from your comment could probably be the issue?

Comment: Working well now!